# nasm program: recursion segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

so this is a Fibonacci program using recursion, 
but there's a "Segmentation fault (code dumped)" in the end. what causes this?
the code:

```
_start:
mov eax, 4  ; ask for a number
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt
mov edx, promptLen
int 80h

mov eax, 3  ; scan input
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, n
int 80h 

sub byte [n], 30h

mov esi, 1
push word 0
push word [n]
call fibo

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

fibo:
    mov ebp, esp

    mov edi, [ebp+6]

    add byte [ebp+6],30h    
    mov eax, 4              ; print number
    mov ebx, 1
    lea ecx, [ebp+6]
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h
    sub byte [ebp+6],30h

    mov eax, 4  ; print space   
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, space
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    cmp byte [ebp+4],0
    je bye

    add [ebp+6],esi
    mov esi, edi

    push word [ebp+6]

    dec word [ebp+4]
    push word [ebp+4]

    call fibo

    bye:
    ret 4
```

sampe output:

```
Enter a number: 5
0 1 1 2 3 5 Segmentation fault (code dumped)
```

the output numbers are correct but what causes the seg fault?

Comment: Wouldn't gdb be able to tell you the exact instruction causing the seg fault???

Comment: i don't know what gdb is. sorry.

Comment: Strongly suggest you keep your stack dword aligned!

Comment: how do i do what you guys are saying? im still learning nasm.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you popping or adding any value to the esp. Be sure to have esp the same value as at the start of the call. You can do that by saving the base pointer on the stack.
In each function remember to do this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
;at the end of the function
pop ebp
```

after calling a function where you pushed some registers, be sure to do:

```
add esp, 4*x
;where x is the number of registers you pushed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing words on a 32-bit stack. This is "legal" but probably a bad idea. You "might" just get it to work, but `add [ebp + 6], esi` is killin' ya. This is clobbering 4 bytes on the stack, not just the 2 you intend. Just changing this to `si` "might" fix it, but I'd suggest using dwords throughout. Your `ret 4` is removing 2 (word!) parameters from the stack - this is "stdcall", which is unusual in Linux, but "should" work. I'd do it the way coolbartek shows.